# Enthought canopy not running the file.

Tags: python, enthought

i just downloaded Enthought Canopy and have reinstalled it 3x now with no luck.

everything opens just fine, it just wont compile and run.

It also has  a shortcut to Pylab on my desktop and that seems to compile just fine, but the editor doesn't.

thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. You'll need to be much more specific before anyone will be able to help. Start with a trivial example. For example, if you use the editor to create a python file containing the single line `print "hello"`, and press the Run button, exactly what happens?

Comment: @JonathanMarch Hi, Thanks for your response, when I create such a program, no matter how simple it doesnt allow me to hit run. The problem is that it doesn't allow me to run/compile. On the other hand, the shortcut to Pylab that it created on my desktop executes code and files without a problem.

Comment: Thanks for filing a support request. Responded there for further investigation.